# Kusto - percentile() on a time series with missing values

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I'm a bit stuck with trying to calculate the 95th centile figure for some data from a time series which has been summarised into 1-minute bins over a 24 hour period, but where some of the bins are missing due to no data being recorded during those bins.

For example given this table, which has already been summarised into bins from the raw data:

```
datatable (Timestamp: datetime, MaxRUsPerSecond: double)
[
    '2020-07-06 00:01:00', 1,
    '2020-07-06 00:20:00', 10
]
```

If I simply add `| summarize percentile(MaxRUsPerSecond, 95)` it will give me the value `10` which is mathematically correct, but it ignores the 18 missing minute-by-minute samples which should be treated as zero value.

In effect, the result I really want calculated is this, which gives a 95th centile as `1`:

```
datatable (Timestamp: datetime, MaxRUsPerSecond: double)
[
    '2020-07-06 00:01:00', 1,
    '2020-07-06 00:02:00', 0,
    '2020-07-06 00:03:00', 0,
    '2020-07-06 00:04:00', 0,
    '2020-07-06 00:05:00', 0,
    '2020-07-06 00:06:00', 0,
    '2020-07-06 00:07:00', 0,
    '2020-07-06 00:08:00', 0,
    '2020-07-06 00:09:00', 0,
    '2020-07-06 00:10:00', 0,
    '2020-07-06 00:11:00', 0,
    '2020-07-06 00:12:00', 0,
    '2020-07-06 00:13:00', 0,
    '2020-07-06 00:14:00', 0,
    '2020-07-06 00:15:00', 0,
    '2020-07-06 00:16:00', 0,
    '2020-07-06 00:17:00', 0,
    '2020-07-06 00:18:00', 0,
    '2020-07-06 00:19:00', 0,
    '2020-07-06 00:20:00', 10,
]
| summarize percentile(MaxRUsPerSecond, 95)
```

I started looking at weighted percentiles using `percentilew` but it felt like I was starting down a rabbit hole trying to append a synthetic bin to account for the missing ones, and then working out what weight to give it based on the number of missing bins, so I stopped for a minute to see if anyone else has a better idea.

For context, I'm trying to get the maximum throughput (RU/s) per minute from a CosmosDB account. This is the query I've got so far:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(24hr)
| where Category == "DataPlaneRequests"
| summarize ConsumedRUsPerSecond = sum(todouble(requestCharge_s)) by collectionName_s, _ResourceId, bin(TimeGenerated, 1sec)
| summarize MaxRUsPerSecond = max(ConsumedRUsPerSecond) by collectionName_s, _ResourceId, bin(TimeGenerated, 1min)
```

Basically, get the total Consumed RUs for each collection into 1-second bins, and then get the maximum value of those for each minute. If I can then get the 95th centile of those (somehow including the missing 1-minute bins) it will tell me whether I can scale down some of our collections to smaller throughputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you can fill missing values in arrays, first option is to use the [make-series](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/make-seriesoperator) operator and specify the 'default' argument to the value that you want to use to replace the missing values or use one of the series_fill functions such as [series_fill_linear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/series-fill-linearfunction).

Once you created the arrays, you can expand them using [mv-expand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator) operator and calculate the percentiles.

Here is an example:

```
let Start = datetime(2020-07-06 00:01:00);
let End = datetime(2020-07-06 00:21:00);
datatable (Timestamp: datetime, MaxRUsPerSecond: double)
[
    datetime(2020-07-06 00:01:00), 1,
    datetime(2020-07-06 00:20:00), 10
]
| make-series MaxRUsPerSecond= any(MaxRUsPerSecond) default =0 on Timestamp from Start to End step 1m
| mv-expand MaxRUsPerSecond to typeof(double), Timestamp to typeof(datetime)
| summarize percentiles(MaxRUsPerSecond, 95)
```

Comment: Amazing - thanks for this. I'm querying Log Analytics via the REST API and your answer came exactly as I was about to starting coding up a client-side version of ```make-series``` in my app so I could munge the partial data locally, but now I don't have to - it's probably saved me days of headaches :-).